# How to find out video codec that is playing?

Tags: google-cast

I have a DASH manifest with multi-codecs and I need to log the video codec. Shaka [documentation](https://github.com/google/shaka-player#dash-features) says that "[it] will negotiate support with the browser and choose the best ones". Is there a way to find out which codec ends up being chosen? I know that Shaka can provide that information via `Player#getVariantTracks()` but I don't see the player instance being exposed by the receiver.